# Create a dynamic forum in android

Tags: android, user-forums

I am very new developer in android. I want to create a dynamic platform where users can share texts, like twitter. I started to create the interface first, but I don't have any idea, where to start.

I just searched as;
how to build dynamic forum in android
how to build an application where users posts texts

but, coudn't get what i need.

i'm open to every suggestion(these suggestions can be books, links, tutorials, video tutorials) i want to the my planned project as soon as possible. i'm very willing to do this project. maybe what i concern about is very easy in a technical way, but now they just started to get me down. i feel myself so beginner and won't rise to the challenge.

Comment: In general, questions like this will simply get down-voted as they are not appropriate for StackOverflow and is better discussed elsewhere.

They are right as well. Your question is too broad and too unspecific. "How do I create twitter or a forum on Android" is not much different than asking "How do I make an operating system". Sure, the complexities are different but broadness of the question is relatively the same. Please try to make this question specific. For instance, do you know how to make the server side code?..

Comment: [Cont] How to program your database? How to implement the required messaging? Is your problem only on the Android side of things and you already have a working server enabled with some sort of API you app can call? If so, what is your specific problem? If not, I suggest starting from your server side and then thinking about the Android side. Remember, people go to university to study computer science and spend years and years programming for a reason. What you want to do spawns multiple fields of software engineering and there isn't a single book that will teach you everything.

Comment: kha you're great, thanks for your comment. i don't have any part of what you have said. i will start from scratch. as i said i'm a beginner. i need a guide, because now, everything seems very scary.. what should i learn first? server side? database?

Comment: Is going to uni to study comp-sci an option? :). You need all of them. Mastery in at least one programming language, very good understanding of databases and decent understanding of computer architecture, specially how to design an scalable architecture are the minimum requirements to do what you want to do properly. If you want to hack around though, start with an easy and popular option (like PHP + MySQL) and work yourself up. There are plenty of tutorials on how to write simple forums in PHP + MySQL. Read them, understand them and adapt them to your use-case. After that, think about how...

Comment: [Cont] ... you can expose the same functionalities in your server to your app via a JSON API and then learn Android programming and implement it in your app.